# How do I taunt specifically with my weapon?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Team Fortress 2 [recently introduced a number of changes to taunts](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/June_18,_2014_Patch), including a menu to choose among taunts and the ability to perform “partner taunts” with members of the opposing team.

The problem is, if I try to [taunt kill](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Taunt_kill#Special_taunts) an enemy who is currently, say, doing the conga, I end up dancing along with them instead — I don't even get the taunt menu. I take offense to this perfect defense!

**How can I perform my *weapon taunt* even if there is a partner taunt I could join?**

Comment: (I could have titled this question "How do I kill dancing people?")

Comment: I don't think they expected anyone to not want to do the conga.

Comment: New surefire way to defend against taunt kills - Conga!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the only way to avoid this is to begin your taunt far enough away from the conga that you are actually allowed to do your weapon taunt, then pray your enemy congas right into it. I do wish there were a more positive answer for this question, but if you consult the [wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Conga) you'll see this on the item text.

> This is a group taunt. Other players can join you by activating their weapon taunt.

Given that your weapon taunt is where your tauntkill is, using it while near a conga is not going to happen.

Comment: I love to use the showdown taunt behind the dancers, because of its fast speed and huge range.